# Javascript referring to wildcard object name

Tags: javascript, arrays, wildcard

I am setting multiple objects outside of my function as so:

```
var object1 = { header:"Lorem ipsum 1", description:"Lorem ipsum 1" };
var object2 = { header:"Lorem ipsum 2", description:"Lorem ipsum 2" };
var object3 = { header:"Lorem ipsum 3", description:"Lorem ipsum 3" };
```

I now have a loop within my function to create a new element for each of these objects' content to be displayed in.

How would I refer to them within the variable I am setting for the element content with a wildcard for the unique number after "object"?

```
var element = '<div class="element"><div class="header">'+object1['header']+'</div><div class="description">'+object1['description']+'</div></div>';
```

Obviously, at this point the "1" after object is hard coded, I have tried to add the number dynamically for each of the loops and the number is set in a "num" variable, how would I place that between "object" and "['header']" and it still parse the whole string as a var to extract "header" from my object?

Comment: put the arrays(object as pointed out) into an array

Comment: I was looking for a way to have individual options inside one array and I was given this "object" syntax from the site I found, I just assumed it was a type of array, updated the question, I am new to JS baring in mind. I didn't think to place each of them into a new array, I will try that now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is an *array* containing the *objects* you've defined. An array is defined with a set of square brackets like so:

```
var emptyArray = [];
var numbers = [1, 2, 3];
```

So in your case you can place your objects in to an array like this:

```
var elementData = [
    {
        header: 'Lorem ipsum 1',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum 1'
    },
    {
        header: 'Lorem ipsum 2',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum 2'
    },
    ...
]
```

Then you can iterate through them with a `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < elementData.length; i++) {
    var data = elementData[i];
    var element = '<div...>' + data.header + '...' + data.description;
    // Do stuff with element
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was trying to workout how to do and it seems really simple now, just couldn't find an example of it.